# Why is Color Tinting Overlay using the ruby minimagick gem running on top of ImageMagick not working as expected?

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, minimagick

Given a source image `input.png`, to which I would like to add a color overlay of `#292929` to, [according to the ImageMagick guides](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#tint_overlay), it's possible to do with the following command, to generate an `output.png`:

```
convert input.png \( +clone -fill '#292929' -colorize 100 \) -compose overlay -composite output.png
```

When using [minimagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick), it seems like this ought to be possible to replicate with the following series of instructions in ruby (assuming that all dependencies are present):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mini_magick'

MiniMagick.configure do |config|
  config.debug = true
end

MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |convert|
  convert << 'input.png'
  convert.stack do |stack|
    stack.clone.+
    stack.fill('#292929')
    stack.colorize(100)
  end
  convert.compose('overlay')
  convert.composite('output.png')
end
```

However, the command that's generated under the hood by minimagick is oddly this, with the resulting error:

```
[0.03s] convert input.png ( -fill #292929 -colorize 100 ) -compose overlay -composite output.png
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.3.6/lib/mini_magick/shell.rb:18:in `run': `convert input.png ( -fill #292929 -colorize 100 ) -compose overlay -composite output.png` failed with error: (MiniMagick::Error)
convert: no images defined `output.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3230.
    from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.3.6/lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:79:in `call'
    from /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/mini_magick-4.3.6/lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:40:in `new'
    from ./convert.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

It looks like `+clone` is not added in between the parens, which helps explain the error, but still does not explain *why* it's not added in between the parens, given [this](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick#stacks) documentation.

I am not certain that this is a bug in minimagick, or my misunderstanding of the docs, but that's basically the gist of it.

Comment: I don't use minimagick, but this may help... https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/286

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, [next issue](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/286#issuecomment-154548274) surfaces when attempting the suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a [bug](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/341#issuecomment-154552271) in minimagick.

In the meantime, the suggested temporary workaround is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mini_magick'

MiniMagick.configure do |config|
  config.debug = true
end

MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |convert|
  convert << 'input.png'
  convert.stack do |stack|
    stack << '+clone'
    stack.fill('#292929')
    stack.colorize(100)
  end
  convert.compose('overlay')
  convert.composite('output.png')
end
```